# How to get Android TextToSpeech to read from a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView that pulls data from a ContentProvider via a CursorLoader.

I want to have a button that reads out the data in the ListView when pressed. The tricky part is that the data in the ListView is continually updating (data from the ContentProvider changes periodically every few seconds) and the data for each row might update while the audio is being read.

How do I make it such that the latest data is read each time it is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
private boolean ttsEnabled= true;
private Thread ttsThread = null;
private ListView lastState = null;

public void enableTTS() {
    ttsEnabled = true;
    ttsThread = new Thread(ttsRunnable);
    ttsThread.start();
}

public void disableTTS() {
    ttsEnabled = false;
    try {
        ttsThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Runnable ttsRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (ttsEnabled) {
            if (lastState == null || !lastState.equals(yourListView)) {
                // List view updated, tts here
                lastState = yourListView;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you explain the `booleanThatTellsIfListViewUpdated` part?